# What is the best approach when a table can be joined with multiple parents

Tags: database, database-design

I have multiple situations in my DB like this:
- request table (main action in my app, have 15 fields, biggest one is varchar 255)
- request details (linked with request, have 20 fields, 4 of them are varchar 2000)

Now, I have multiple JOIN tables with request details like Countries, Products, etc.

My question which is the best approach of the table structure of those joined tables from the performance perspective (like queries). For example:
1) request_id, request_details_id, country_id
2) request_details_id, country_id
3) request_id, country_id

Some pro and cons will be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Keep in mind, even if a Country table can be requested as a detail, joined to many different other tables its cardinality is low, rarely updated and we can even call it a domain table

Comment: [mre] please. PS There's no "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461/266284)

Comment: Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.)